# Get URL of Job in mail body in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I have Job in Jenkins that sends an email after the build with a HTML report in its body using 
[email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) by setting Default content to this :

```
${FILE,path="absolute_path/index.html"}
```

I want to add to this (my body mail ) the URL of the build of this job. How is that possible ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`$BUILD_URL` is the easiest way to do it, just add it in your Body mail and it will show the hyperlink of your latest build.

Comment: $BUILD_URL returns http://localhost:8080/job/TestProject/16/

and 

$PROJECT_URL returns http://localhost:8080/job/TestProject/

Comment: Configure `JENKINS_URL`: Configure System > Jenkins URL

Answer (score 24):

*Small update to this question:*

First of all, you need to set `Jenkins URL` in your system configuration to access such URLs:

Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> `Jenkins URL`

*It set to `http://localhost:8080/` by default (if you accepted this during initial start of Jenkins)*

> Optionally specify the HTTP address of the Jenkins installation, such
>   as http://yourhost.yourdomain/jenkins/. This value is used to let
>   Jenkins know how to refer to itself, ie. to display images or to
>   create links in emails.
>
> This is necessary because Jenkins cannot reliably detect such a URL
>   from within itself.

Then you can access the build or job URLs via `BUILD_URL` or `JOB_URL` environment variables in your Groovy pipeline script.

For example:

```
println env.BUILD_URL
println env.JOB_URL
```

You also can find more such environment variables for your Jenkins instance on this page:
http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html/ (replace `localhost:8080` with your Jenkins URL)

Answer (score 1):

`${PROJECT_URL}` in the body of email will be resolved to a hyperlink to your job.

Comment: I get null for PROJECT_URL

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Specified in the Default content under editable email configuration in Jenkins

//build_url is fetched the URL of Build
//allure/ its append with URL for Allure reporting browser URL

${FILE,readFile("$BUILD_URL/allure/")